# Returning correct value using react-select and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-forms Controller api around AsyncSelect from react-select to load options as the user types from an external API.  Everything works fine except the returned value is coming back as the string `"[object Object]"` instead of the fullName property from the object.

My component:

```
           <Controller
            control={control}
            name="businessCategory"
            as={
              <AsyncSelect
                className="react-select-container"
                loadOptions={v => handleAutocompleteLookup(v)}
                onChange={handleCategoryInputChange}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
                getOptionValue={option => option.fullName}
              />
            }
          />
```

My handleChange function.  SetValue is from react-hook-form:

```
  const handleCategoryInputChange = newValue => {
    return setValue('businessCategory', newValue, true);
  };
```

Any my data is an array of objects with the following shape:

```
{
  fullName: "DJ service"
  id: "gcid:dj"
  name: "DJ service"
  publisher: "GMB"
}
```

Any clues on this would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 55):

Update your code in following way

**In your import**

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from 'react-select';
```

**In your hook component**

```
function Yourcomponent(props){

    const methods = useForm();
    const { handleSubmit } = methods;
    

    const options = [
     { value: '1', label: 'Apple'},
     { value: '2', label: 'Ball'},
     { value: '3', label: 'Cat'},
    ];
    
    const default_value = 1; // you can replace with your default value
    

    // other codes of the component 
    

    function submitHandler(formData){
    
    // values are available in formData

    }


    return(
      <div>
        
        {* other part of your component *}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)} >

           {* other part of your form *}
            <Controller
                control={methods.control}
                defaultValue={default_value}
                name="field_name_product"
                render={({ onChange, value, name, ref }) => (
                    <Select
                        inputRef={ref}
                        classNamePrefix="addl-class"
                        options={options}
                        value={options.find(c => c.value === value)}
                        onChange={val => onChange(val.value)}
                    />
                )}
            />

           {* other part of your form *}
        </form>

        {* other part of your component *}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: this is an example that worked for me. thank you.

Comment: This solution had a problem with the onChange function for me - what fixed it was using `render={({ field })` and then on the `onChange` property using `onChange={val => field.onChange(val.value)}`.  Maybe im using a newer version of react-hook-form, but the onChange is now a property of the field object.

Comment: but "inputRef" prop is not available for react-select input https://react-select.com/props

Comment: you can just go for ref={ref}

Answer (score 18):

For multi-select (works with react-hook-form v7):

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const {
  control
} = useForm();

<Controller
  control={control}
  defaultValue={options.map(c => c.value)}
  name="options"
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref }}) => (
    <Select
      inputRef={ref}
      value={options.filter(c => value.includes(c.value))}
      onChange={val => onChange(val.map(c => c.value))}
      options={options}
      isMulti
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: `onChange={(val) => onChange(val.value)}` worked for me.

Comment: This is the closest I got myself (with Ali Aref's modification). The only issue is that the Controller's `onChange` function is never triggered :(

Answer (score 6):

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
const options = [
     { value: '1', label: 'Apple'},
     { value: '2', label: 'Ball'},
     { value: '3', label: 'Cat'},
    ];
const {control} = useForm();
<Controller
 control={control}
 name="AnyName"
 render={({ field: { onChange, value, name, ref } }) => (
        <Select
        inputRef={ref}
        classNamePrefix="addl-class"
        options={options}
        value={options.find((c) => c.value === value)}
        onChange={(val) => onChange(val.map((c) =>c.value))}
        isMulti
        />
        )}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I made it work like this:

```js
const options = [
    {value: '', label: ''}
]
```

```js
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";

import Select from "react-select";


const methods = useForm();


<section>
    <label>Label</label>

    <Controller
      as={Select}
      name="Name"
      options={options}
      isMulti
      control={methods.control}
    />

    <ErrorMessage errors={methods.errors} name="Name" />
</section>
```

Comment: I can confirm this works a charm. Just to add for others, pass in all your Select props into the Controller instead.

Comment: It's throwing `TypeError: props.render is not a function` on Controller

Answer (score 5):

well, actually most of these answers don't work for situations where you have a custom onChange function. The trick (seems like a bug) is to set the "onChange(val.value)" inline first and then set your state variable. Here is the full code I have that works;

```
 import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
   const {
       register,
       control,
       formState: { errors },
       handleSubmit,
    } = useForm();

   const handleChangeType = (option) => {
      setItemType(option);
      var options = getOptions(option.value); 
      setList(options);
      setGender(null);
   }; 

    <Controller
      control={control}
      name="itemType"
      rules={{
         required: {
            value: assetType.value == "item",
            message: "Item type is required.",
         },
      }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref, name } }) => (
         <Select 
            className={"react-select"}
            classNamePrefix={"react-select"}
            placeholder={"Item type"} 
            options={itemTypeList}  
            onChange={val => {
                onChange(val.value);
                handleChangeType(val); 
            }} 
         />
      )}
   /> 
   {errors.item?.message && <div class="validationText">{errors.item?.message}</div>}
```

Comment: I was looking for a onChange solution for update a state(context), thanks! In this example is possible use the 'name' atribute on handleChangeType too.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post what worked for me. I used **react-select**, **react-hook-form**, and **@hookform/error-message**:

I created a function as follows

```
  const handleCategoryInputChange = (newValue: any) => {
    console.log(newValue.value);
    return setValue('contract', newValue.value);
  };
```

My react select looks like this:

```
<Controller
  name="contract"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, name, ref } }) => (
    <ReactSelect
     // value={contractData.find((c) => c.value === value)}
     // onChange={(val) => onChange(val)}
     onChange={handleCategoryInputChange}
     options={contractData}
     ref={ref}
     name={name}
     defaultValue={contractData[0]}
     theme={customTheme}
     isSearchable={false}
     className="block w-full min-w-0 flex-1 sm:text-sm"
/>
)}
/>
<ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="contract" message="Select a Contract" />
```

I don't think my className is working properly you can ignore that part. It is working for my specific set up though lol. The commented out code did not work the way I wanted because when i console logged the data I got it as follow:

```
contract: {label: 'contract name', value: 'contract name'}
optionPeriods: "dfd"
performanceEndDate: "2022-12-08"
performanceStartDate: "2022-12-08"
proposalDueDate: "2022-12-08T12:54"
requirements: "dfd"
trackingNumber: "dfd"
```

so I commented out that specific solution and did it the way you see now and i get the exact data i want for my contract as you can see below:

```
contract: "contract name"
optionPeriods: "dfd"
performanceEndDate: "2022-12-08"
performanceStartDate: "2022-12-08"
proposalDueDate: "2022-12-08T12:54"
requirements: "dfd"
trackingNumber: "dfd"
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**What worked for me is:**

- react-hook-form v7.45.2
- react-select 5.7.4

```js
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from "react-hook-form"

const { register } = useForm();

const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

return (
    <Controller
        control={control}
        defaultValue='give_it_a_default'
        name="give_it_a_name"
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field, value, name, ref }) => (
            <Select
                name={field.name}
                inputRef={field.ref}
                options={options}
                value={options.find((c) => c.value === field.value)}
                onChange={val => field.onChange(val.value)}
            />)
      )}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by approaching it with a custom register via react-hook-form as seen here:

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Registerfields

Comment: Can you please share more details?